# How to switch case with string

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
type Etat struct {
    gorm.Model
    Value string `form:"value"`
}

func New(value string) Etat {
    switch value {
    case 'Recette':
        return Etat{Value :value}
    case 'Production':
        return Etat{Value :value}
    default:
        panic("unrecognized value")
    }

}
```

And here is the error that I got :

```
.\MicroConf.go:23:2: invalid case '\u0000' in switch on value (mismatched types rune and string)
.\MicroConf.go:23:7: invalid character literal (more than one character)
.\MicroConf.go:25:2: invalid case '\u0000' in switch on value (mismatched types rune and string)
.\MicroConf.go:25:2: duplicate case '\u0000' (value 0) in switch
    previous case at .\MicroConf.go:23:7
.\MicroConf.go:25:7: invalid character literal (more than one character)
```

I truly don't understand how it's not working. I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Switch)

Comment: Interpreted string literals use quotes, not apostrophes: `"Recette"` instead of `'Recette'`. Or backtick when you use raw string literal `\`Recette\``. Apostrophes are used in rune literals.

Comment: use double quotes instead of single like `"Recette"` instead of `'Recette'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your New function must looks like:

```
func New(value string) Etat {
    switch value {
    case "Recette", "Production":
        return Etat{Value :value}
    default:
        panic("unrecognized value")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use double quotes instead of single quote in case expresion

```
case "Recette":

instead of

case 'Recette':
```

by the way, better to change your function name from New() to something else