# Strange error message: mismatched types rune and string

Tags: go

I am new to Go programming and I am having a problem with my program which uses a "switch" statement to process the value retrieved from a "map".

The map is declared as follows:

```golang
var fields_map map[string]string
```

A value is later retrieved as follows:

```golang
f_code, ok := fields_map["function"]
```

If "ok" has a true value I then do a "switch" on the retrieved code as follows

```
    switch f_code {
        case "meta":
        case "users":
        case "history":
        default:
    }
```

My problem is that for each of the "case" statements I get an error as follows :
invalid case '\u0000' in switch on f_code (mismatched types rune and string)

According to one webpage I found "rune" is defined as follows:
The Go language defines the word rune as an alias for the type int32

Why am I getting this error ? And why the reference to "rune" ?
Both the key and value for my map are declared as "string" , so I am confused.

Any ideas ?

I have created a reduced version of my code which has the same compile errors

```
     1  package main
     2  
     3  import (
     4      "fmt"
     5  )
     6  
     7  var fields_count int
     8  var fields_map map[string]string
     9  
    10  func parse_fields() {
    11      fields_count = 0
    12      fields_map = make(map[string]string)  // initialize the map
    13  
    14  } // parse_fields
    15  
    16  func main() {
    17  
    18      parse_fields()
    19      f_code, ok := fields_map["function"] // test for existance of function code
    20      if ok {
    21          switch f_code {
    22              case 'meta':
    23                  break;
    24              case 'users':
    25                  break;
    26              case 'history':
    27                  break;
    28              default:
    29                  break;
    30          }// switch
    31      } else {
    32          fmt.Println("<H3>No function code detected</H3>")
    33      }
    34  
    35  } // main
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the map is not a map[string]string, but a map[string]rune.

Comment: my declaration said nothing about a "rune". why would the GO compiler complain about a rune?

Comment: Try reducing the code as much as possible, then post the whole reduced code and/or a link to it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/). If we can't see actual source, we all just have to guess.

Comment: Like so: https://play.golang.org/p/ZEMJ76Bq-SV

Comment: You only post a portion of the code. Based on that: either the declaration is not what you said it is; or f_code or fields_map is shadowing another variable; or the switch-case you pasted here is not the same as what you're compiling.

Comment: Here is a reduced version of the code which has the same compile errors

Comment: @BarryKimelman I have edited my answer accordingly: try and run https://play.golang.org/p/woB1gYR1KYC

Comment: thanks. my code now compiles. Not sure why it wasn't compiling earlier with double quotes!!

Answer (score 3):

This error (`invalid case '\u0000'`) was [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53480788/6309), and means you have not used actual double-quotes for your case values:

```
switch f_code {
    case 'meta':
    case 'users':
    case 'history':
    default:
}
```

If you replace them by `"`, it should work, considering your map (and `f_code`) are using string.

The OP's example is in [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5blDUr-4ETB), and does indeed generate the `illegal rune literal` error.

Using double-quotes, as in [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/woB1gYR1KYC), would yield no error.

```
parse_fields()
f_code, ok := fields_map["function"] // test for existance of function code
if ok {
    switch f_code {
    case "meta":
        break
    case "users":
        break
    case "history":
        break
    default:
        break
    } // switch
} else {
    fmt.Println("<H3>No function code detected</H3>")
}
```

Comment: replacing the double quotes with single quotes does not change anything. i still get the same error messages

Comment: @BarryKimelman replace the single quotes with double quotes, rather than vice versa.

Comment: I have tried using both single and double quotes. in both cases I get the same bunch of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The reflect package is used to get the type of the value, you can switch over based on types as well.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
    )

func main() {
     myMap := map[string]string{ "test1":"testing", "test2":"testing2" }
     value, ok := myMap["test1"]
     fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value), value)
     if (ok) {
           switch value {
               case "debug1":
                  fmt.Println("not what i meant")
               case "testing":
                  fmt.Println("This is what i am looking for")
               default:
                  fmt.Println("default value ")
           }
      }
}
```

output:

string testing

This is what i am looking for